# Converting latex highlighted code listing to image

Tags: listings, minted, svg

Does someone know how I could submit a paper to a journal which contains source code highlighting with `minted` https://github.com/gpoore/minted ?
I really like the highlighting and don't want to go back to `lstlisting`, however I somehow doubt the journal editors will have the latest Tex Live installation as well as `pygments` installed in their python installation.

Is there a way maybe to convert the `minted` code `listings` to svgs and put these in their stead in the latex document?

Comment: Copy your minted setup and the actual code to a new document with class `standalone` and you get a pdf file.

Comment: Good idea. I tried it with standalone (which requires by the way the varwidth option to compile) but it's cutting off my line numbering and the border lines

Comment: try `border=1cm` as global option. I don't know how minted typesets stuff, and there isn't anything to test, so this is all guessing.

Comment: Hey, nice, the border fixed it. Now I just need to crop the pdf and I can insert it as a figure in my main document. Thanks!

Comment: *I really like the highlighting and don't want to go back to `lstlisting` [...]* Why not? It's usually possible, with marginal effort, to set up `listings` to highlight code like `minted` would. IMO, that would be preferable to having listings as images.

Comment: @Jubobs “It's usually possible, with marginal effort” — It really isn’t, which is [why I originally started work on minted to begin with](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1966425/1968).

Comment: @KonradRudolph Poor choice of words on my part. I didn't mean to denigrate `minted`, which is more powerful than `listings` in many respects.

Answer (score 3):

As per [@Johannes_B](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/37907/johannes-b) suggestion, I created a separate tex file for each code listing which I then compile to pdf and use as figures in my original document. I used document class standalone to create a separate pdf file for each code listing.

```
\documentclass[varwidth=6cm, border={0.5cm 0.1cm 0.1cm 0.1cm}]{standalone}
\usepackage{minted}
\setminted[python]{breaklines, linenos, frame=lines, framesep=2mm, fontsize=\footnotesize, numbersep=5pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{python}
cool = python.code()
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Being in the same situation and having many code listings, I didn't want to make a separate tex file for each listing. I found that by declaring the `minted` environment as a "standalone environment", on line 4 below, you can have multiple listings that get separate pages in the produced pdf:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=6cm, border={0.5cm 0.1cm 0.1cm 0.1cm}]{standalone}
\usepackage{minted}
\setminted[python]{breaklines, linenos, frame=lines, framesep=2mm, fontsize=\footnotesize, numbersep=5pt}
\standaloneenv{minted}
\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{python}
cool = python.code()
\end{minted}

\begin{minted}{python}
more_cool = python.code()
\end{minted}

% Many more minted blocks go here

\end{document}
```

Using the nice `pdftk` program we can split this into one pdf per page:

```
$ pdftk document-name.pdf burst
```

which gives us pdf files named `pg_NNNN.pdf` with NNNN ranging from 0001 and up. Each page is cropped on the left, top and bottom correctly, but they have some whitespace on the right such that all of them have the width specified in the class option. By setting `varwidth` to be the desired line width in the paper, this works very well with `includegraphics`.

To get floats named "Listing 1" etc. in the other document (where these pdfs are included now as graphics), one can put the following in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{ruled}
\newfloat{listing}{thp}{lop}
\floatname{listing}{Listing}
```

and then in the document body

```
\begin{listing}[htbp]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pg_0001.pdf}
\caption{Showing some code.}
\label{lst:somecode}
\end{listing}
See the code in \cref{lst:somecode} for an example.
```